# Python list reduce function

Tags: python

I have a list of values:

```
val = [array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 5, 10]), array([4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 6, 6, 7]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9])]
```

All i want to do is apply a function to each of the elements and save the new computed values like:

```
val = val.apply((lambda x: myfunct(x)))
```

But it gives me an error.

Comment: Not sure where you found `.apply()`. The function is [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), as in `map(myfunct, val)`.

Comment: "But it gives me an error" -- why not say what that error is?